# QMdiArea in TabbedView glitch on tab switching

Tags: qt, mdi, qtabbar

I have QMdiArea initialized like this:

```
m_pMdiArea = new QMdiArea(this);
m_pMdiArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
m_pMdiArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
m_pMdiArea->setTabsClosable(true);
m_pMdiArea->setDocumentMode(true);
m_pMdiArea->setTabsMovable(true);
m_pMdiArea->setViewMode(QMdiArea::TabbedView);
```

When I open several tabs and switch between them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, here is how the window looks after several iterations:

[image: Initial]
[image: Ctrl+Tab]
[image: Ctrl+Tab+Tab]

When I release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the new tab is selected and everything is fine. But why it looks so strange during the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Qt 5.3.2 there appears to be a bug whereby Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab in tabbed MDI areas cause the sub window to be drawn. See [QTBUG-42612](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-42612).